# Different outputs from the same C program

Tags: c, pointers

i have a pointer problem:

```
            SearchResults* pointy;

            pointy = returnResults();

            if(pointy != NULL && pointy->results[0] != NULL)
            {
                HandleResponse();
                printf("sharp");

            }else{
                //do other things
            }

            if(pointy == NULL){
                    printf("blunt");
            }
            if(pointy->results[0] == NULL){
                printf("wah!!!");
            }
```

in the debugger the code correctly works and i get "sharp" but under the same conditions in the bash terminal i get "wah!!!"

```
   typedef struct SearchResults
   {
   TreeNode* results[40];
   int searchIndex;
   } SearchResults;

   SearchResults*  lostAndFound;




 SearchResults* returnResults()
 {
  return lostAndFound;
  }
```

Comment: What is `returnResults()` doing?

Comment: did you mean `!=` rather `==` in the title?

Comment: We'll some more code to identify that problem. Or atleast how are you invoking the program

Comment: Abhi it is part of the search function of a server(605 lines) && binaryTree(300 lines) that is ale to return multiple results. pointy->results[n] should be a pointer to a tree node

Comment: Suggest `pointy` and/or `pointy->results[0]` is not initialized, thus Undefined Behavior (UB).

Comment: Definitely need more code. If the program is over 900 lines, then you need to make it smaller to isolate the problem. You can't expect us to debug a 900 line program ever, but certainly not when you only show 25 lines of it. We're not magicians. "Should be a pointer to a tree node" isn't good enough - it "should be" working fine, but it obviously isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Problem in both the debug and release variations there is a .csv file.. the debug reads and writes to it perfectly fine whereas the release seems to steamroll it into nothigness.